# Repeat rows three times and and replace the titles based on a predetermined format in R

Tags: r

I don't think I can explain this in the title well.  So an example is shown!  I have 10K+ records goes like this.

```
Data <- data.table(
  Time= sample(1:50),
  Values = sample(1:50),
  Locations= sample(c("PlaceA","PlaceB","PlaceC"),50 , replace= TRUE),
  TitlesFormat1= sample(c("TitleA", "TitleB","TitleC"), 50, replace = TRUE),
  key=c("TitlesFormat1,Time")
)

Data$TitlesFormat2<-paste0(Data$TitlesFormat1,"_(topic)")

Data$TitlesFormat3<-paste0(Data$TitlesFormat1,"_(",Data$Locations,"_topic)")

head(Data)

 Time Values Locations TitlesFormat1   TitlesFormat2      TitlesFormat3
   2     49    PlaceC      TitleA     TitleA_(topic) TitleA_(PlaceC_topic)
   6     41    PlaceA      TitleA     TitleA_(topic) TitleA_(PlaceA_topic)
   8     40    PlaceA      TitleA     TitleA_(topic) TitleA_(PlaceA_topic)
  13     15    PlaceB      TitleA     TitleA_(topic) TitleA_(PlaceB_topic)
  14     11    PlaceC      TitleA     TitleA_(topic) TitleA_(PlaceC_topic)
  18     17    PlaceC      TitleA     TitleA_(topic) TitleA_(PlaceC_topic)
```

Each observation has 3 possible title formats as shown.  I want each row to repeat 3 times but each time with a different TitlesFormat so it looks like this:

```
 Time Values   Locations        Titles  

   2     49      PlaceC         TitleA      
   2     49      PlaceC         TitleA_(topic)   
   2     49      PlaceC         TitleA_(PlaceC_topic)        
   6     41      PlaceA         TitleA     
   6     41      PlaceA         TitleA_(topic)    
   6     41      PlaceA         TitleA_(PlaceA_topic)      
   ...   ...     ...            ...
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before we get to the answer, a couple of points:

- Please use `set.seed(.)` if you're using `sample`, for reproducibility.
- The idiomatic way in `data.table` is to use `:=` operator to add/update columns, by reference. Else, there's no advantage to using `data.table`s.

---

You can use `melt.data.table` function to get your data.table into long format:

```
require(reshape2)
ans <- melt(Data, id=1:3)[, variable := NULL]
#      Time Values Locations                 value
#   1:    3     44    PlaceA                TitleA
#   2:    7     15    PlaceC                TitleA
#   3:   12      3    PlaceC                TitleA
#   4:   13      7    PlaceA                TitleA
#   5:   15     13    PlaceC                TitleA
#  ---                                            
# 146:   43     36    PlaceB TitleC_(PlaceB_topic)
# 147:   44     46    PlaceB TitleC_(PlaceB_topic)
# 148:   46      6    PlaceC TitleC_(PlaceC_topic)
# 149:   48     29    PlaceC TitleC_(PlaceC_topic)
# 150:   50     11    PlaceB TitleC_(PlaceB_topic)
```

If you'd like it in the same order you've shown, then:

```
ans[, .SD, by="Time,Values,Locations"]
#      Time Values Locations                 value
#   1:    3     44    PlaceA                TitleA
#   2:    3     44    PlaceA        TitleA_(topic)
#   3:    3     44    PlaceA TitleA_(PlaceA_topic)
#   4:    7     15    PlaceC                TitleA
#   5:    7     15    PlaceC        TitleA_(topic)
#  ---                                            
# 146:   48     29    PlaceC        TitleC_(topic)
# 147:   48     29    PlaceC TitleC_(PlaceC_topic)
# 148:   50     11    PlaceB                TitleC
# 149:   50     11    PlaceB        TitleC_(topic)
# 150:   50     11    PlaceB TitleC_(PlaceB_topic)
```

---

Following @Ananda's benchmark, I realise that we could get away with a simple `order()` instead of using `.SD` here:

```
ans[order(Time, Values, Locations)]
```

`order()` within DT is optimised to use `data.table`'s fast ordering (from v1.9.3+), and therefore this should be much faster than the previous `.SD` version.

Here are the updated timings:

```
# Unit: milliseconds
#     expr        min         lq    median        uq       max neval
#  fun1a()  137.79719  154.68321  210.5660  242.4496  565.8980    50
#  fun2a()   92.80878   96.90226  139.4311  166.3089  472.6021    50
#  fun1b()  750.38312  828.79247  855.2852  940.3480 1151.7485    50
#  fun2b() 1059.37594 1238.60744 1332.6860 1417.6680 1502.5817    50
#  fun2c()  474.23736  543.14490  580.7551  623.6124  819.4660    50
```

where `fun2c()` is:

```
fun2c <- function() {
    melt(Data, id=1:3)[, variable := NULL][order(Time,Values,Locations)]
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your advice!  I am new to R so your answer is really helpful! I will definitely be aware of the two points you made! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another alternative using "dplyr" + "tidyr". This is more for the sake of providing variety, but it also performs pretty well. The benchmarks also show that rearranging the row order later is actually quite an expensive operation.

The approach is as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

Data %>%
  gather(Var, Val, TitlesFormat1:TitlesFormat3) %>%
  group_by(Time, Values, Locations) %>%
  select(-Var)
```

---

Testing it out on a larger set, here's some sample data:

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 1000000
Data <- data.table(
  Time = sample(n),
  Values = sample(n),
  Locations = sample(c("PlaceA","PlaceB","PlaceC"), n, TRUE),
  TitlesFormat1 = sample(c("TitleA", "TitleB","TitleC"), n, TRUE),
  key = "TitlesFormat1,Time"
)

Data$TitlesFormat2 <- paste0(Data$TitlesFormat1, "_(topic)")

Data$TitlesFormat3 <- paste0(Data$TitlesFormat1,
                             "_(",Data$Locations,"_topic)")
```

Here are some functions to test:

```
fun1a <- function() {
  Data %>%
    gather(Var, Val, TitlesFormat1:TitlesFormat3) %>%
    select(-Var)
}

fun1b <- function() {
  Data %>%
    gather(Var, Val, TitlesFormat1:TitlesFormat3) %>%
    group_by(Time, Values, Locations) %>%
    select(-Var)
} 

fun2a <- function() {
  melt(Data, id=1:3)[, variable := NULL]
}

fun2b <- function() {
  melt(Data, id=1:3)[, variable := NULL][, .SD, by="Time,Values,Locations"]
}
```

And here are the timings:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(fun1a(), fun2a(), fun1b(), fun2b(), times = 50)
# Unit: milliseconds
#     expr        min         lq     median        uq      max neval
#  fun1a()  116.08640  174.88565  321.20920  406.0018  475.027    50
#  fun2a()   85.71839   87.13557   97.65836  163.5093  423.566    50
#  fun1b()  856.71950 1049.25575 1107.36416 1227.6997 1406.043    50
#  fun2b() 1159.17395 1322.75210 1392.12119 1434.5502 1543.636    50
```